# Comparison of 2 populations in Matlab

Tags: matlab, mean, difference

in many papers, when comparing 2 populations, I often see that the means where adjusted for potential confounders (age, sex, etc..).

Is there a function in matlab that I can use to do so? Is n-way ANOVA sufficient?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ANCOVA. ANCOVA is a type of ANOVA used to control for confounding factors. MATLAB has [aoctool](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/analysis-of-covariance.html) that does this

Comment: Hi Thanks! What of I have more than 1 confounder factor? for example Age and Gender? As far I understood ANCOVA can have only one as input

Comment: Then it's MANCOVA. There's a MATLAB central submission [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27014-mancovan)

Comment: Thanks again. Is it better than a weighting adjustment?